# Auth::user() returns null

Tags: php, authentication, laravel-5, middleware

I use Laravel 5.2 and have a problem with middleware.
There is the code in the routes.php

```
    use Illuminate\Contracts\Auth\Access\Gate;


    Route::group(['middleware' => 'web'], function () {

        Route::auth();

        Route::get('/', 'HomeController@index');
    });


    Route::group(['prefix'=>'admin',  'middleware' => 'admin'], function(){
        Route::get('/', function(){
            return view('admin.index');
        });
        Route::get('/user', function(){
            return view('admin.user');
        });
    });
```

Kernel.php:

```
    protected $routeMiddleware = [
    ...
     'admin' => \App\Http\Middleware\AdminPanel::class,
    ];
```

AdminPanel.php

```
    namespace App\Http\Middleware;


    use Closure;
    use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Auth;
    use App\Role;

    class AdminPanel
    {
        public function handle($request, Closure $next)
        {
            $user = Auth::user();
            dd($user);

            if($user){
                $role = Role::whereName('admin')->first();
                if($user->hasRole($role)){
                    return $next($request);
                }
            }
            return redirect('/');
        }
```

So,

```
$user = Auth::user()
```

always return null.
Thanks for suggestions!

Answer (score 58, accepted):

Any route that uses `Auth()` must be encapsulated in the `web` middleware. You're close, just move your `Route::group(['prefix' => 'admin'], ...)` into the group above.

```
Route::group(['middleware' => 'web'], function () {

    Route::auth();

    Route::get('/', 'HomeController@index');

    // Moving here will ensure that sessions, csrf, etc. is included in all these routes
    Route::group(['prefix'=>'admin',  'middleware' => 'admin'], function(){
        Route::get('/', function(){
            return view('admin.index');
        });

        Route::get('/user', function(){
            return view('admin.user');
        });
    });
});
```

Comment: In my case I created a custom route file as routes/admin.php and hooked it inside boot() method of RouteServiceProvider.php. Since I wanted to have Auth::user() working inside my middleware I needed to pass ``web`` as `first` element of array which I passed to middleware chaining. i.e `Route::prefix('admin')->middleware(['web', 'admin'])->namespace($this->namespace)>group(base_path('routes/admin.php'));`. Passing it first element is important as it wont work as second.

Answer (score 84):

I faced a situation where `Auth::user()` always returns `null`, it was because I was trying to get the `User` in a controller's constructor.

I realized that you can't access the authenticated user in your controller's constructor because the middleware has not run yet.

As an alternative, you can define a Closure based middleware directly in your controller's constructor.

```
namespace App\Http\Controllers;

use App\User;
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Auth;
use App\Http\Controllers\Controller;

class ProjectController extends Controller
{
    protected $user;

    /**
     * Create a new controller instance.
     *
     * @return void
     */
    public function __construct()
    {
        $this->middleware(function ($request, $next) {

            $this->user = Auth::user();

            return $next($request);
        });
    }
}
```

Comment: This solves my problem, and I put all the process inside the middleware callback;

Answer (score 3):

Define middleware in the constructer of your controller and it will do the trick here

```
public function __construct()
{
    $this->middleware('auth:api');
}
```

Answer (score 1):

I had the same problem because i did not set the table name.

```
/**
 * The table associated with the model.
 *
 * @var string
 */
protected $table = 'users';
```

Comment: thank you so much, I spent quite some time to fix this issue. In the past I added table attribute to each model

Answer (score 1):

I found a solution in an old code

```
    function getAuth($guard, $get)
{
    return auth($guard)->user()->$get;
}
```

add this ^ as a helper function and use it wherever you want
ex:

```
getAuth('user', 'id');
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use it like this.

```
$this->middleware(function ($request, $next) {
            //Your Code Here 
            return $next($request);
        });
```

It has worked for me.

Answer (score -1):

just include your authentication middleware in call

```
$user = auth('middleware')->user()
```

Answer (score -2):

```
Route::middleware('auth:api')->group(function () {
    Route::get('/details', 'UserController@details');
});
```

Comment: `middleware('auth:api')` supports to only api requests

Answer (score -6):

My `Auth::user()` return `null` in view when

- I don't have **users** table in database
- I don't have **id** field as primary key of table **users**