# Laravel 8 auth returns null

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-8

Problem:

- On my index page, authenticated users and guests should be able to view and use the page unless they want to save something. I tried to log in so that I could save the data and was redirected to an authenticated page which is a profile page. I tried dumping `Auth::user()` on the profile page, it returns the user logged in data, tried dumping it again on the index page then it returns null.

I'm using the latest version of Laravel.

I've googled some of the same problems I have and the closest one is this [Auth::user() returns null](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35160144/authuser-returns-null). I tried following the answer provided but still, it returns null.

web.php

```
Route::group(['middleware' => 'web'], function () {
    Route::get('/', [IndexController::class, 'index'])->name('index.page');

    Auth::routes();
    
    Route::group(['middleware' => ['auth:user']], function() {
        Route::get('/user/profile', [UserController::class, 'profile'])->name('user.profile');
    });

    Route::group(['prefix' => 'admin', 'middleware' => ['auth:admin']], function() {
        Route::get('dashboard',[DashboardController::class, 'index'])->name('admin.dashboard');

    });
})
```

auth.php

```
'defaults' => [
    'guard' => 'web',
    'passwords' => 'users',
],

'guards' => [
    'web' => [
        'driver' => 'session',
        'provider' => 'users',
    ],
    'user' => [
        'driver' => 'session',
        'provider' => 'users',
    ],
    'admin' => [
        'driver' => 'session',
        'provider' => 'admins',
    ],
],

'providers' => [
    'users' => [
        'driver' => 'eloquent',
        'model' => App\Models\User::class,
    ],

    'admins' => [
        'driver' => 'eloquent',
        'model' => App\Models\Admin::class,
    ],
],
'passwords' => [
    'users' => [
        'provider' => 'users',
        'table' => 'password_resets',
        'expire' => 60,
        'throttle' => 60,
    ],
    'admins' => [
        'provider' => 'admins',
        'table' => 'password_resets',
        'expire' => 15,
   ],
],
```

This is the only modification I did from the middleware.

RedirectIfAuthenticated.php

```
foreach ($guards as $guard) {
   if ($guard === "admin" && Auth::guard($guard)->check()) {
       return redirect('/admin/dashboard');
   }

   if ($guard === "user" && Auth::guard($guard)->check()) {
       return redirect('/user/profile');
   }

   if (Auth::guard($guard)->check()) {
       return redirect('/');
   }
}
```

I added `$guard` for the User and Admin model

User.php

```
protected $guard = 'user';
```

Admin.php

```
protected $guard = 'admin';
```

If you have any questions, feel free to ask and thanks for the help!

Comment: it returns `null` with admin only? Did you try to clear the cache?

Comment: @MohamedGamalEldin no, it returns null either of them as long as I'm going back to the index page it will always return null but not on the authenticated pages. Already clear my cache after customizing `auth.php`.

Answer (score 0):

But i guess the customized Auth.php has a problem

```
 foreach ($guards as $guard) {
   if ($guard === "admin" && Auth::guard($guard)->check()) {
       return redirect('/admin/dashboard');
   }else{
       if ($guard === "user" && Auth::guard($guard)->check()) {
          return redirect('/user/profile');
       }else{
          return redirect('/');
       }   
   }

}
```

Comment: It still returned as null with or without that code. I'm not really sure where the problem is right now and thanks :)

Comment: please try the edited code

Comment: and please tell me where you `dd(Auth::user());`

Comment: dump is on the controller but it returns null when on the index page but not on the profile page which is still the same.

Answer (score -1):

I can share the solution that worked for me. I switched from **Passport to Sanctum.**