# i can't get Auth::user(); in laravel

Tags: php, laravel, authentication

AuthController.php

```
public function signinAction(Request $request)
{
    $attempt_data = [
        'username' => $request->username,
        'password' => $request->password
    ];

    $login = Auth::attempt($attempt_data);
    if ($login){
        $admin = Auth::user();
        dd($admin);
        $admin->update(['last_login' => now()]);
        return redirect(route('index'))->with('msg','success login');
    }
}
```

I wanted to get Auth::user(); but $login is true but $admin is null

auth.php

```
'guards' => [
    'admin' => [
        'driver' => 'session',
        'provider' => 'admins',
    ],
    'web' => [
        'driver' => 'session',
        'provider' => 'users',
    ],
    'api' => [
        'driver' => 'session',
        'provider' => 'users',
    ]
],


'providers' => [
    'admins' => [
        'driver' => 'eloquent',
        'model' => App\Models\Admin::class,
    ],
    'users' => [
        'driver' => 'eloquent',
        'model' => \App\Models\User::class,
    ],
```

I change guards
remove admin and change provider change users to admin
i can get Auth::user();
but i want to log in with the
other than 'web'=>[]

```
'guards' => [
    'web' => [
        'driver' => 'session',
        'provider' => 'admins',
    ],
    'api' => [
        'driver' => 'session',
        'provider' => 'users',
    ]
],
```

Comment: What about https://stackoverflow.com/a/35162656/12530661?

Comment: Show your admin model and show your login route