# Laravel : JWT Auth access auth()->user() return null

Tags: php, laravel, jwt, laravel-middleware

I am trying to use JWT for API authentication I am building, I have managed to get the JWT token with code like the following:

```php
$user = User::select('id_user', DB::raw('AES_DECRYPT(id_user, "nur") as username'))
    ->where('id_user', DB::raw('AES_ENCRYPT("' . $credentials['username'] . '", "...")'))
    ->where('password', DB::raw('AES_ENCRYPT("' . $credentials['password'] . '", "...")'))
    ->first();

if (!$user) {
    return response()->json(['error' => 'Unauthorized'], 401);

}

$token = auth()->login($user);
if (!$token) {
    auth()->setUser($user);
    return response()->json(['error' => 'Unauthorized'], 401);
}

return $this->respondWithToken($token);
```

but when you get a logged in user with the `auth()->user()` function it doesn't return anything,

```php
public function me( )
{
    return response()->json(auth()->user());
}
```

my return

```json
{}
```

this is my routes

```php
Route::group(['middleware' => 'api', 'prefix' => 'auth'], function ($router) {
    Route::post('login', [AuthController::class, 'login']);
    Route::post('logout', [AuthController::class, 'logout']);
    Route::post('refresh', [AuthController::class, 'refresh']);
    Route::post('me', [AuthController::class, 'me']);
});
```

and my `config/auth.php` file

```php
    'defaults' => [
        'guard' => 'api',
        'passwords' => 'users',
    ],

    'guards' => [
        // 'web' => [
        //     'driver' => 'session',
        //     'provider' => 'users',
        // ],
        'api' => [
            'driver' => 'jwt',
            'provider' => 'users',
        ],
    ],

    'providers' => [
        'users' => [
            'driver' => 'eloquent',
            'model' => App\Models\User::class,
        ],

        // 'users' => [
        //     'driver' => 'database',
        //     'table' => 'users',
        // ],
    ],
```

the code that I wrote based on the tutorial from [this link](https://jwt-auth.readthedocs.io/en/develop/quick-start/)

I did testing using postman, and the command set the environment automatically. My testing flow is as follows.

1. login,
2. if the token comes out I immediately run the test to run the `me()` function

Answer (score 1, accepted):

i think i got the solution for this problem i am facing. where **jwt-auth** on laravel reads saves the id of our user into the sub in the payload that we created.

and [from this comment](https://stackoverflow.com/a/35162656/10365013) I thought, what if we make our own **custom payload** for **jwt**. here is the code i use.

```php
$payloadable = [
    "sub" => $user->username,
];

$token = auth()->claims($payloadable)->login($user);
```

with that code we create a sub to store my user id.

```php
$payload = auth()->payload()->toArray();
$pegawai = Pegawai::select('pegawai.nama', 'pegawai.jbtn')
    ->where('pegawai.nik', $payload['sub'])
    ->first();
```

it does look inefficient, but at least it can be useful for me to save the original value of the `id_user` that I have encrypted with `AES_ENCRYPT`.

from the first code I made my encrypted data to be decrypted and stored as a username column, and the original value (the result of decryption) I saved in the paylod, in this way I can still get user data while still using `AES_DENCRYPT` and `AES_ENCRYPT` when querying the database, because in the payload that I have contains the original value of my data.

> I don't know why, however, data encrypted with AES_ENCRYPT when returned as json in Laravel returns a value of 0.

I hope that describes and helps

Answer (score 0):

Did you added this code in your controller?

```
public function __construct()
{
  $this->middleware('auth:api', ['except' => ['login']]);
}
```

Comment: Yes, that will help to user, If user is not logged in system then it will redirect to homepage. My opinion is that why we add in construct instead of that we should do in web.php route file